# Implementing a simple state machine with no dynamic allocation and compile time assertion

Tags: rust, state-machine

I'm thinking about a state machine that forces me to implement all state transitions at compile time, so no dynamic allocation is used. I'd like to do

```
let machine = RtspMachine::begin();
machine.event(...);
machine.event(...);
```

and `event` would change the internal state of the machine.

Here's my sketch:

```
struct Init {}

struct Ready{}

struct Playing{}

struct Recording{}

struct _RtspState<T> {
    t: T
}

type RtspState<T> = _RtspState<T>;

trait StateChange where Self: Sized {
    fn from<T>(self, state: &RtspState<T>, event: &Event) -> std::result::Result<RtspMachine, EventError>;
}

impl StateChange for RtspMachine {
    fn from(self, state: RtspState<Init>, event: &Event) -> std::result::Result<RtspMachine, EventError> {
        //...        
    }
    fn from(self, state: RtspState<Init>, event: &Event) -> std::result::Result<RtspMachine, EventError> {
        //...        
    }
    //...
}

pub(crate) struct RtspMachine {
    state: RtspState
}
```

The problem is that in order to ensure in compile time that I implemented all transitions, the `RtspState` must be generic, so I can match over its types. But then, the `RtspMachine` would have to be generic, thus I'd not be able to simply do `machine.event` to modify its internal state because its type would change on a state transition.

I thought of doing

```
enum RtspState {
    Init,
    Ready,
    Playing,
    Recording,
}
```

but then I cannot match over the state, because `RtspState::Init` is not a type, but a variant.

One solution would be to make a `enum RtspMachineWrapper`:

```
enum RtspMachineWrapper {
    RtspMachine<Init>,
    RtspMachine<Ready>,
    RtspMachine<Playing>,
    RtspMachine<Recording>
}
```

but then I'd have to reimplement every `RtspMachine` call to `RtspMachineWrapper` by doing a large match over all states.

What should I do?

Comment: I struggle to see how making `RtspState` generic helps ensure all transitions are covered. Surely the enum supports this more easily via exhaustive matching, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you're confusing two slightly different patterns that are often used with state machines.

The first is to ensure that every transition is handled nicely by encapsulating the FSM in an enum.

```
enum RtspState {
  Init,
  Ready,
  Playing,
  Recording,
}

impl RtspState {
  pub fn on_event(&self, event: &Event) -> std::result::Result<Self, EventError> {
    match self {
      Init => Ok(Ready),
      Ready => if event.foo { Ok(Playing) } else { Err(EventError::new("bang")) },
      ...
      // The compiler will complain if we miss any.
    }
  }
}

pub fn main() -> EventError {
  let state = RtspState::Init;
  let state = state.on_event(an_event());
  let state = state.on_event(foo_event());
  ...
}
```

The other pattern is to create a FSM where invalid events are impossible at compile time. This doesn't use an enum, but uses separate structs as you have in your example. The difference is that only limited events are supported by each struct type.

```
struct Init {}
struct Ready {}
struct Playing {}
struct Recording {}

struct AnEvent {}
struct FooEvent {}

impl Init {
  pub fn on_an_event(self, e: &AnEvent) -> Ready {
    Ready
  }
}

impl Ready {
  pub fn on_foo_event(self, e: &FooEvent) -> Playing {
     Playing
  }
}

pub fn main() {
  let state = Init;
  let state = state.on_an_event(an_event());
  let state = state.on_foo_event(foo_event());
  // The compiler will complain if we try to do an invalid event.
}
```

---

This second form can also be done using traits (as asked by @anon2328).

Here you have (at least) two different ways of doing things, the first and easiest is to use boxed traits.

```
pub trait Init {
 fn on_an_event(self, e: &AnEvent) -> Box<dyn Ready>;
}

pub trait Ready {
 fn on_foo_event(self, e: &FooEvent) -> Box<dyn Playing>;
}

pub trait Playing {}

// You could put all the traits on one object, 
// or you could create separate types for them.
struct AllAtOnce {}

impl Init for AllAtOnce {
  fn on_an_event(self, e: &AnEvent) -> Box<dyn Ready> {
     Box::new(self)
  }
}

impl Ready for AllAtOnce {
  fn on_foo_event(self, e: &FooEvent) -> Box<dyn Playing> {
         Box::new(self)
  }
}

impl Playing for AllAtOnce {}

fn doit(Box<Init> state) {
  let state: Box<Ready> = state.on_an_event(an_event());
  let state: Box<Playing> = state.on_foo_event(foo_event());
}

fn main() {
  doit(Box::new(AllAtOnce));
}
```

The second way is to use associated types:

```
pub struct AnEvent;
pub struct FooEvent;

pub trait Init {
    type Ready: Ready;
    fn on_an_event(self, e: &AnEvent) -> Self::Ready;
}

pub trait Ready {
    type Playing: Playing;
    fn on_foo_event(self, e: &FooEvent) -> Self::Playing;
}

pub trait Playing {}

struct InitImpl;
impl Init for InitImpl {
    type Ready = ReadyImpl;
    fn on_an_event(self, e: &AnEvent) -> Self::Ready {
        ReadyImpl
    }
}

struct ReadyImpl;
impl Ready for ReadyImpl {
    type Playing = PlayingImpl;
    fn on_foo_event(self, e: &FooEvent) -> Self::Playing {
        PlayingImpl
    }
}

struct PlayingImpl;
impl Playing for PlayingImpl {}

pub fn doit<T: Init>(state: T) {
    let state = state.on_an_event(&AnEvent);
    let state = state.on_foo_event(&FooEvent);

    // Gives the error:
    //   no method named `something` found for associated type
    //  `<<T as Init>::Ready as Ready>::Playing` in the current scope
    // state.something();
}

fn main() {
    let state = InitImpl;
    doit(state);
}
```

Comment: In the first case, matching every self and inside of it matching every event would give a giant code for just one impl. Isn't there a way to break it into modules?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=83289195d51a262b3be3dd7aa1f80977 take a look at this example I made. I had to use events with types instead of an enum of events, but I think it works great

Comment: Again, I think you gain very little by adding the generics and separate types in this case: You can find my equivalent version here: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=854cbe2cf7284be72da6f2e8f2095cb8
If I needed special handling for an event-state combination I would then extract that into a separate function.

Comment: Inside the main function inside the last code snippet in the answer, where you have a new `state` variable for each transition - could you do this without knowledge of what the ongoing `state` value is - e.g. in Golang, one could use an interface inside a for loop, a la  `state = state.on_an_event(event)` - is this possible in Rust?

Comment: @anon2328 I've updated the code with examples showing 2 examples of how a trait based approach could work.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it on stack is to use `enum`.

You can skip useless variants of `enum` while matching:

```rust
match my_enum_value {
    MyEnum::Value1(state) => { /* do something */ },
    MyEnum::Value2(state) => { /* do something else */ },
    _ => { /* do nothing? */ },
}
```